# read memory from pointer

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have a function like this:

```
int __stdcall sub_57BBD0(int a1, int a2, int a3, char a4)
{
  *(_BYTE *)a3 = *(_BYTE *)a1;
}

*(BYTE*)(a1 + 0) is a pointer to a BYTE*
```

from the pointer of `a1`, how can I get the `BYTES` data that this that pointer points to? or is it impossible?, Because `a1` points to a `BYTE*` in memory, I can `ReadProcessMemory` to get the data, but can I do it another way?

I've tried doing:

```
BYTE *data = *(BYTE*)&a1;
```

but it's not working,

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Misleading title; this isn't really about function pointers. Are you trying to reverse-engineer a function? Where did you get this code? What do you mean by "get the BYTES data"? (Looks like that's what the function is already doing.)

Comment: I'm trying to reverse a function yes, a1 is a pointer to a array of bytes, I'm trying to work out how to get the data, I know that's what it's doing here  *(_BYTE *)a3 = *(_BYTE *)a1;

How I don't know how to do it and reference it into a variable.

Comment: If `a1` is a `BYTE *`, why not write `(BYTE *a1, ...)` in the prototype?  Or, if it points to a `BYTE *`, why not write (BYTE **a1, ...)`? It's a lot easier (and more reliable) than type-punning `int` to pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mmmm, this code looks pretty dirty.  Is it a disassembly or something?

Anyway, the value `a1` seems to be a pointer that is used as an `int`.  You have this:

```
*(_BYTE *)a3 = *(_BYTE *)a1;
```

That is taking the first `_BYTE` value from the memory location that `a1` points to and storing it in the memory location that `a3` points to.

If you want to get the pointer itself, then just don't dereference it:

```
BYTE *data = (BYTE*)a1;
```

All you are doing here is type-casting from an integer to a `BYTE*` (which I assume is the same as `_BYTE`).

Now you can reference `BYTE` values from `data` as if it was an array (assuming that the memory is actually allocated to your process):

```
BYTE secondVal = data[1];
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
BYTE * data = *(BYTE*)&a1;
```

This line says, get the address of the integer, a1, cast it to a BYTE pointer, dereference it and get the value of it, and then assign that to a BYTE pointer called data.

So you'll want to do this instead:

```
BYTE data = *((BYTE *)&a1);
```

Comment: do you mean BYTE *data = *((BYTE *)&a1); ? I'm a little confused now

Comment: Why will getting the adress of the parameter on the stack help?

Comment: @Dean No, he doesn't. You want `BYTE data`, `BYTE* data` is a pointer to a `BYTE` and that would best be set to the value obtained from dereferencing the first pointer leaving you only one level of indirection.

Comment: No, I mean exactly what I typed. You said that you want to get the data that the BYTE pointer points to, if I'm not mistaken. My code basically says: Get the address of a1 (which is int), and cast it into a byte pointer. Then dereference (get the value) that's pointed to by that byte pointer.

Comment: oh okay but wouldn't that just be one byte? and not all the data?

the function does   *(_BYTE *)a3 = *(_BYTE *)a1; to get the data, how can I do the same thing but reference it?

Comment: Yes, it will only give you one byte of data. If you want all 4 bytes (assuming you have 32 bits per int), you would need to increment the address of the pointer, and then get the value at that address, three more times. In the code snippet that you just provided, you're only transferring one byte of data, and not all 4 bytes anyways.